# Replace frame range with image in a video with python

Tags: python, video, video-processing

I would like to create a script that will replace some part of a video with images (e.g. with slides of a presentation).

My idea for now is to replace every frame in a range with a an appropriate image corresponding to a presentation slide.

I would like to do it with Python, what libraries would you recommend?

Edit: format does not matter for me, I can always convert before processing.

Comment: What video format? .mkv, .avi, .mp4... etc.. It's kinda important.

Comment: Does not matter - avi would be fine, I can always convert before.

Comment: Ok i've added a short AVI example below how to read and write AVI data. Note that for future reference specifying it does matter because there are people here that downvotes the answer if you later on disconver that you want a AVI solution for instance :)

Comment: thank you for your answer but it does not really show how to put images into a frame. I also know pymedia tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you didn't specify a format, here's how to in AVI format:

http://pymedia.org/tut/

Recording from one file to another (split the frames you need):

```
#! /bin/env python
import sys
import pymedia.video.muxer as muxer
import pymedia.video.vcodec as vcodec

def recodeVideo( inFile, outFile, outCodec ):
    dm= muxer.Demuxer( inFile.split( '.' )[ -1 ] )
    f= open( inFile, 'rb' )
    fw= open( outFile, 'wb' )
    s= f.read( 400000 )
    r= dm.parse( s )
    v= filter( lambda x: x[ 'type' ]== muxer.CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO, dm.streams )
    if len( v )== 0:
        raise 'There is no video stream in a file %s' % inFile

    v_id= v[ 0 ][ 'index' ]
    print 'Assume video stream at %d index: ' % v_id
    c= vcodec.Decoder( dm.streams[ v_id ] )
    e= None
    while len( s )> 0:
        for fr in r:
            if fr[ 0 ]== v_id:
                d= c.decode( fr[ 1 ] )
                if e== None and d:
                    params= c.getParams()
                    params[ 'id' ]= vcodec.getCodecID( outCodec )
                    # Just try to achive max quality( 2.7 MB/sec mpeg1 and 9.8 for mpeg2 )
                    if outCodec== 'mpeg1video':
                        params[ 'bitrate' ]= 2700000
                    else:
                        params[ 'bitrate' ]= 9800000
                    # It should be some logic to work with frame rates and such.
                    # I'm not aware of what it would be...
                    print 'Setting codec to ', params
                    e= vcodec.Encoder( params )
                if e and d:
                    dw= e.encode( d )
                    #print 'Frame size ', len( dw )
                    fw.write( dw )

        s= f.read( 400000 )
        r= dm.parse( s )

if __name__== '__main__':
  if len( sys.argv )!= 4:
    print "Usage: recode_video <in_file> <out_file> <format>\n\tformat= { mpeg1video | mpeg2video }"
  else:
    recodeVideo( sys.argv[ 1 ], sys.argv[ 2 ], sys.argv[ 3 ] )
```

There's also other libraries, for instance for Matroska files:

- https://github.com/vi/mkvparse